# NSGA-II with flight ticket reservation

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am totally confused with this optimization problem. Since I am a beginner for this evolutionary algorithms, if I asked a basic question, please forgive me. I checked many NSGA II examples. They took flight ticket reservation as a standard problem to explain two-objective optimization problem. I clearly understand the concept that for example, if we want to choose low cost and a few hours of traveling time, it is really hard to find best from multiple combinations as bellow. For example, if we have the following combinations,

[image]

How can I generate the initial population--> Chromosome. Since ticket types are Pareto front, how can I represent individuals (Chromosomes)?